# Mixed Model: Am I artificially inflating my data?

Tags: mixed-model

I have a question about whether I'm artificially adding degrees of freedom in my mixed model.
I am testing whether brain volume predicts my outcome measure. However, I have two measures of brain volume: left hemisphere and right hemisphere. I am not interested in how left and right are different per se, so could average, but I tend not to just throw away information. So I tried the model below.

Subjects have one outcome per time point. Volume comes in two hemispheres. My data is structured like this:

```
ID    TimePoint    Hemisphere    Volume  OUTCOME
A001    1          Left          1234    0.64
A001    1          Right         1365    0.64
A001    2          Left          1456    0.90
A001    2          Right         1356    0.90
A001    3          Left          1456    0.94
A001    3          Right         1345    0.94
A002    1          Left          1567    0.35
A002    1          Right         1200    0.35
A002    2          Left          1233    0.67
A002    2          Right         1245    0.67
...
```

Volume data is different for each row. OUTCOME data is collected only at time points, so replicated for each hemisphere within a timepoint.

using lme4 I do something like:

```
lmer(OUTCOME ~ TimePoint * Hemisphere * Volume + 
    (1 + TimePoint * Hemisphere | ID), data = data)
```

Is this right? Or am I double counting my outcome per hemisphere. Is there a way to account for the dependency in OUTCOME by hemisphere by random effects.
Thanks so very much in advance,

MixedUp Modelr

Comment: Have you missed some formatting? What is TimePointHemisphereVolume ?

Comment: In your sample data, the outcome is the same for each subject/timepoint combination. Is this always true (e.g., the outcome is some behavioral measurement that can't be assigned to an individual hemisphere), or is the just a coincidence?

Comment: Couple clarification questions: Are there only two time points?  And are you anticipating a three-way interaction between time, hemisphere, and hemispheric volume? As written, it seems to me you would get some result like "At time point 1, people with a 1 unit increase in volume in the left hemisphere had an outcome score [blank] units higher/lower than those at time point 2." Something seems off but I can't quite put my finger on it yet.

Comment: You might need to explain what the aim of your model is.

Comment: In my real dataset there are three time points. In the model, instead of timepoint, I code for change in time since start of study. I collect one outcome measure per timepoint (hence the duplication or outcome values by hemisphere). I could split the dataset and run the analysis in left, then run it in right, but in truth I think of the left and right volumes as measures of a more latent variable, hence trying to put it in the same model.

Comment: Yes it is always true that the outcome is the same for each hemisphere. I collect a volumetric measure of a brain structure at each time point, one for left brain, one for right brain...My feeling is going towards no, this setup pretends there is double the data that I actually have.

Comment: Edited to reflect comments